# google-python-api-client refresh token is null

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-fit, google-python-api

I am trying to use refresh tokens with the google-python-api-client to avoid having to have the user authenticate the app every time.

I have the following code that builds the fitness service by having the user authenticate every time

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
import httplib2

scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read"
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, scope, redirect_url)
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print auth_uri

token = str(input("Enter token"))

cred = flow.step2_exchange(token)
storage = Storage("credentials_file")
storage.put(cred)

storage = Storage("credentials_file")
cred2 = storage.get()

http = httplib2.Http()
http = cred2.authorize(http)
service = build('fitness', 'v1',http=http)
```

However, repeatedly authenticating is obviously not ideal so I am trying to convert this into code that can refresh access token using a refresh token. However, after running this code, cred.refresh_token and cred2.refresh_token are both None. How can I obtain the refresh token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, I figured out why it's null

This line:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, scope, redirect_url)
```

Needs to be edited as follows:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            scope,
            redirect_url,
            approval_prompt='force'
)
```